# share point standard search

Tags: search

SharePoint Standard Search can be configured to search through_**__**

A. 
LOB applications, file folders, People Search, SharePoint content.

B. 
LOB applications, outlook mails, SharePoint Content.

C. 
None of the options.

D. 
File Folders, SharePoint Content, Exchange Server Content.

Comment: MOSS or SP2010?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 Standard search can crawl:

**Out of the BOX**

- SharePoint
- Web/HTTP
- File share
- Exchange Public Folders
- Lotus Notes DBs

**Download from MS**

- Documentum

**Develop/Buy**

- Business Connectivity Services (BCS) connectors

Answer (score 0):

you can find all detailed information for sharepoint 2010 standard and enterprise

check this:
http://www.khamis.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=6c8a23d1-47ea-47e5-b56f-2bc57cb95b93&ID=61&Web=d64cd8b3-a3f4-40d8-8d93-6aa6dc82fcda